# C# Division expression generator - Only MOD 0s

Tags: c#, time, division, generated, modulo

I want to generate a set number of division questions. These questions must give an integer answer and not real number. 
Here's my code:

```
        int tempNum1, tempNum2; 
        do // Cannot give decimal answers for students
        {
            tempNum1 = numGen.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            tempNum2 = numGen.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        } while (tempNum1 % tempNum2 != 0);
        return String.Format("{0}/{1}", tempNum1, tempNum2);
```

Return values are stored in array, ready to be displayed.
The problem is that generating takes too long; are there any solutions without needing to change the minV and maxV?

Comment: If you want to generate questions of type `a/b = c`, where all numbers are integers, don't randomly draw `a` and `b` but draw `b` and `c` then calculate `a = b * c`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to take random 2 numbers, multiply them and then divide multiplication result on one of the arguments  to get mod 0?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you generate the questions by multiplying?

```
int tempNum2 = numGen.Next(minValue, maxValue);
int f = numGen.Next(minValue, maxValue);
int tempNum1 = tempNum2 * f;
return String.Format("{0}/{1}", tempNum1, tempNum2);
```

---

Of course you would need to adjust `maxValue` for `f` to find numbers in the desired range.

Comment: btw: is this part of a homework? I'm sure some month ago there was an identical question...but can't find it anymore.